# findAncestorsTree doesn't return parents in TypeORM 3

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm using TypeORM materialized tree. There's an entity called `organization`, every organization has a parent and could have several children.

```
@Entity('organizations')
@Tree('materialized-path')
export class Organization {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @TreeChildren()
  children?: Organization[];

  @TreeParent()
  parent?: Organization;
}
```

I call `findAncestorsTree` to fetch parents of a child in tree. Based on TypeORM document it should return all direct child's parent organizations (with "parent of parents") but it only return the child item without any parent.

```
const organization = await this.organizationRepository.findOne({
   where: { id },
});
return this.dataSource.manager.getTreeRepository(Organization).findAncestorsTree(organization);
```

The response that I get:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "A3-121"
}
```

What I expected to get:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "A3-121",
    "parent": {
       "id": "2",
       "name": "A2-12",
       "parent": {
           ...,
           "parent": {
               ...
           }
       }
    }
}
```

How can I fetch all the parents of a sub organization in a tree?

Used packages:

```
"typeorm": "^0.3.16"
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For now, I've used a recursive function to get by.

```js
function getAllNestedParents(obj: any): any[] {
    if (!obj?.parent) {
      return [];
    }

    const parents: any[] = [obj.parent];
    return parents.concat(getAllNestedParents(obj.parent));
  }
```

Please replace the `any` types with your use case.